# Issue in rendering angular bootstrap calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was using angular bootstrap calendar from github

```
https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar
```

It was working fine with one project and when tried to implement in a new project i can't make the (year/month/week/day) view work.I have created a pen with html/js and all necessary files

```
https://codepen.io/iammelvin/pen/jwXxoe
```

Any help would be really appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: you should remove the tag FullCalendar. This is a tag for a specific product called FullCalendar developed by Adam Shaw.. which you are not using.

Comment: @Mych you find that in the pen i created.I don't see so ?

Comment: I have remove the tag in your question (not the pen)

Comment: Oh i see sorry for adding that i thought it would be relevant.